# Use an element from a parsered Java DOM XML to add a new element

Tags: java, xml, dom

Okay so I am working on a program that calculates something then takes that data and adds it to an existing XML file in the same directory. I have used DocumentBuilder to parse the file and now need (at least this is what I think I need to do, please correct me I am wrong) to get an element from the parsered file and appendChild another element to it.

Here is the code so far
The imported packages:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
```

and the function that actually parsers and edit the XML file:

```
public void saveIt(){
        DocumentBuilder bd = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = bd.parse("excersize.xml");
        Element root = doc.getElementsByTagName("root");
        Element today = doc.createElement(today);
        root.appendChild(today);
    }
```

When I try to compile this code here are the errors I get (fyi, this is a custom-made cmd):

```
Good Luck Sir: javac excersize.java
excersize.java:240: error: incompatible types
                Element root = doc.getElementsByTagName("root");
                                                       ^
  required: Element
  found:    NodeList
excersize.java:241: error: method createElement in interface Document cannot be
applied to given types;
                Element today = doc.createElement(today);
                                   ^
  required: String
  found: Element
  reason: actual argument Element cannot be converted to String by method invoca
tion conversion
2 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `doc.getElementsByTagName("root")` returns `NodeList` so change it,

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
```